# Monitor black border

Tags: graphics-card, display, border

I have two monitors model iiyama pl2792q with the same problem: They have a black border at top, left and right, but *not* at bottom.

With the underscan/overscan option I can only make the content smaller (it is already at 0% overscan). Described in this answer: https://superuser.com/a/232082

I changed the resolution from 1920x1080 to 1920x1200 - no solution.

Graphics card: AMD Radeon HD 6700 Series

Windows 7

Is it possible, that this black border is a hardware problem?

[image]

Comment: How are the monitors connected? VGA? DVI? HDMI?

Comment: One HDMI the other DVI